# Music players with ALSA output option

Tags: 16.04, alsa, music-player

Currently using `kubuntu` 16.04 with `deadbeef` player. I would really like different gui cause of the ammount of music on my drive, `deadbeef` is not a good idea when you have 1tb+ music. I've tried clementine and other players from this thread 
http://www.head-fi.org/t/561961/bit-perfect-audio-from-linux
Turns out I can't select ALSA in any of them except `deadbeef`, no such option. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

**JRiver Media Center**

JRiver Media Center works with ALSA. Unfortunately it's not free. You need to purchase JRiver License (either Linux Licence or Master Licence). You have 30 days to try the full feature set.

**Guayadeque**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:anonbeat/guayadeque
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install guayadeque
```

after install, go to the terminal and run

```
 aplay -l
```

find your bit perfect device number and sub number.

Open Guayadeque and go to the `View>Preferences>Playback` and set device to the ALSA and `hw:DeviceNumber,subNumber`. For example, `hw:0,0`.

**GMusicBrowser**

```
sudo apt install gmusicbrowser
```

After install, just go to the Settings>Output Device>output device (ALSA)> advance options and set ALSA device (For example: `hw:0,0`).

Comment: I am aware of it. I used to use it for every media file i've got. Sadly its Linux version is paid and pretty bad.

Comment: I updated my answer. i'm currently using gmusicbrowser and i'm quite happy with it.

Comment: Add Audacious (https://audacious-media-player.org/). It does not handle large libraries the same way gmusicbrowser does, but allows direct ALSA output to an external DAC.

Answer (score 1):

If you like the look of Amarok 1.4 and Clementine, but want an updated player with more advanced settings for audio output, you can check out [my fork of Clementine called Strawberry](https://github.com/jonaski/strawberry/releases)

It's aimed at audio enthusiasts and users who play local music files.
It has support for multiple backends (gstreamer, xine and VLC), with advanced audio device options, like setting a custom alsa device string.

Here is a picture of Strawberry compiled on Ubuntu

[image: Strawberry]